# Javascript embedded in svg not executing on one url but is executing in another url? Why?

Tags: javascript, svg

In the original url:

https://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpu-bash-flamegraph.svg

You're able to click into the bars on the flamegraph

But in the following (which has the exact same source code for the svg) you can't. Why?

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Argus-Labs/world-engine-profiles/main/testing.svg

Tried this on chrome and firefox. Seems like some browser security feature? How would I enable it in the second link?

Comment: I'm seeing errors in the browser console.  Many more of them on the "not working" site.  Have you started there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the domain `raw.githubusercontent.com`. For security reasons, it includes a very strict [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) header on every response[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

I'm not sure yet which aspect exactly is blocking the script embedded in the SVG file. But you can try downloading the file and opening it locally to see that the SVG itself has no problems. It also sounds like a reasonable security restriction for Github: you don't want users uploading avatar images with embedded Javascript, for example.

If you want to host content like this on Github, I suggest using https://pages.github.com/ instead.

[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)

> Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; base-uri 'self'; child-src github.com/assets-cdn/worker/ gist.github.com/assets-cdn/worker/; connect-src 'self' uploads.github.com [www.githubstatus.com](http://www.githubstatus.com) collector.github.com raw.githubusercontent.com api.github.com github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com github-production-repository-file-5c1aeb.s3.amazonaws.com github-production-upload-manifest-file-7fdce7.s3.amazonaws.com github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com cdn.optimizely.com logx.optimizely.com/v1/events api.githubcopilot.com objects-origin.githubusercontent.com *.actions.githubusercontent.com wss://*.actions.githubusercontent.com productionresultssa0.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa1.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa2.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa3.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa4.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa5.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa6.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa7.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa8.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa9.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa10.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa11.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa12.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa13.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa14.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa15.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa16.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa17.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa18.blob.core.windows.net/ productionresultssa19.blob.core.windows.net/ github-production-repository-image-32fea6.s3.amazonaws.com github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com insights.github.com wss://alive.github.com github.githubassets.com; font-src github.githubassets.com; form-action 'self' github.com gist.github.com objects-origin.githubusercontent.com; frame-ancestors 'none'; frame-src viewscreen.githubusercontent.com notebooks.githubusercontent.com; img-src 'self' data: github.githubassets.com media.githubusercontent.com camo.githubusercontent.com identicons.github.com avatars.githubusercontent.com github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com objects.githubusercontent.com secured-user-images.githubusercontent.com/ user-images.githubusercontent.com/ private-user-images.githubusercontent.com opengraph.githubassets.com github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com customer-stories-feed.github.com spotlights-feed.github.com objects-origin.githubusercontent.com *.githubusercontent.com; manifest-src 'self'; media-src github.com user-images.githubusercontent.com/ secured-user-images.githubusercontent.com/ private-user-images.githubusercontent.com github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com gist.github.com github.githubassets.com; script-src github.githubassets.com; style-src 'unsafe-inline' github.githubassets.com; upgrade-insecure-requests; worker-src github.com/assets-cdn/worker/ gist.github.com/assets-cdn/worker/